# How to use other language code in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll, pascal, chuck

I am interested in integrating language from another audio programming language ([ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)) into my Delphi project. I know that maybe that is possible with dynamic-link libraries (.DLLs) but I am not familiar with this.

Does anyone know how I can configure a project to get the two languages working together?

Comment: Usually you can find some wrappers written in Delphi by some other experienced Delphi users. Always google them first.

Comment: Can you tell me what is a wrapper? I am new to these concepts

Comment: Some classes or functions/procedures providing the interfaces for you to use those DLLs in Delphi.

Comment: Is it even allowed for you to use other programming language in your assignment besides Object Pascal (Delphi)? You see when your professor will be grading your assignment it won't be grading it based on final capabilities of your program that you make for this assignment but based on how you have implemented these features, based on which coding style has you used and so on. ...

Comment: Now if you go and use two different programming languages in your project then you make grading of your work for your professor to be much more difficult. Why? Each programming language has its own preferred coding style so the professor would have to see if you did used preferred coding styles in different parts of your code. Also what would happen if your professor does not know Chunk at all. Then he won't even be able to grade you at all. So first thing you have to do is ask your professor if you are even allowed to use other programming languages for your final assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Yes, I still have to talk with my professor about this. Most of the program will be written in delphi, but for example, to program midi related stuff it would be easier to do it from chuck rather than delphi. Also this is something I am personally into, so I would use this beyond my final assignment

Answer (score 3):

A quick glance at the [ChucK documentation](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/) suggests three possible approaches, all arising from the fact that ChucK is both a language and also a virtual machine (VM) to run the programs written in that language.

ChucK is open source, so the full source code of that VM is available but is written in C++.  ChucK is available either in this source code form or as a ready-to-run executable for the supported platforms.

I could find no reference to any DLL version of the VM for use within other programs.  Which isn't to say that such a DLL has not been developed by others, only that I couldn't find any reference to one and it does not appear to be part of the standard distribution of ChucK itself.

I did find [some source code which references a DLL in the context of ChucK](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~prc/ChucKU/CalArtsMar2014/ExtendChucK/CHUGS/chuck/include/chuck_dl.h) but it was not entirely clear to me whether this was a DLL API for using ChucK or part of the implementation, allowing ChucK itself to be modularised or extended via DLL's.

The three options I see before you are:

1. Port the Chuck VM to Delphi.  That is, translate all of the ChucK VM source code to Delphi.  This will give you a version of ChucK implemented entirely in Delphi which is capable of running ChucK programs.
2. Implement a DLL API (possibly based around or starting from that link above) for the existing ChucK VM source code in C++ in a way that enables you run ChucK programs by calling into that DLL to be run by the existing C++ implementation of ChucK.
3. Run ChucK programs using the ChucK exe using ShellExecute(), WinExec() or CreateProcess() etc, just as you would if you wished to run any other external program from a Delphi program.

These are presented roughly in descending order of difficulty.  That is, a full port to Delphi (Opt 1) is likely to be beyond your capability.

Implementing a DLL interface around the existing C++ code (Opt 2) may be possible depending on your C++ and Windows development skills.

Calling an external program (Opt 3) is relatively straightforward.

Which approach is right for you depends on the nature of your assignment, the objectives, and your confidence/skills in the areas involved.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get different systems talking to each other is use Open Sound Control (OSC). ChucK has [OSC receivers and senders](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/) (search for "> OSC") built into it and [Delphi](http://opensoundcontrol.org/implementation/delphi-osc) looks like it implements OSC as well.

OSC works over networks but you can also just send messages to your own local machine (localhost). The ChucK examples do this referenced above do this.

It's not a tight integration but it'll get the Delphi-ChucK relationship going.